# "Before proceeding you must first launch Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and accept the End User License Agreement"

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, preview, adobe

What can I do with this on Mac?

The App Adobe Acrobat Reader DC is installed on mac, and when i launch that app, nothing pops up to accept any license.

It makes, I cannot open pdf file in browser:

This is screenshot of popover in my native polish language:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trash the Adobe Reader app, go to `/Library/Internet Plugins` and remove ‘AdobePDFViewer.plugin’ and ‘AdobePDFViewerNPAPI.plugin’, then re-download Adobe Reader and install it again.